# Is certain matlab-routine used in matlab script?

Tags: matlab, function, reflection, dependency-management

I am running a big m-file that I didn't write myself and that depends on certain subfunctions. I want to know if anywhere in all nested functions a particular function (in my case the function eig.m (to calculate eigenvalues) ) is used.
Is there a quick way to do this?

kind regards,
Koen

Comment: What is Matlab Routine? Please Tell

Comment: Matlab script/program that while matlab is running, saves the names of all matlab-scripts it uses

Comment: My Professor said "MATLAB routine means facilities available in the matlab itself" is it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **semi-documented** function `getcallinfo` (see [Yair Altman's blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/function-definition-meta-info) for more information about it):

> `getcallinfo`
>
> Returns **called functions** and their first and last lines 
>       This function is unsupported and might change or be removed without
>       notice in a future version.

### General use of `getcallinfo`

Let's create an **example script** which contains **subfunctions** (this works [in  Matlab R2016b](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html) or newer) and save it as `'filename.m`'. The procedure also works if there are **nested functions**, or if the main file is a **function** instead of a script.

```
x = input('');
y = find(x);
z = f(norm(x));
disp(z)
function u = f(v)
    u = -log2(v) + log2(pi);
end
```

Then:

```
>> g = getcallinfo('filename.m');
```

gives you a **nested struct array** with interesting information, including function calls. The first entry, `g(1)`, refers to the main file. There may be further entries for subfunctions or nested functions. In this case, `g(2)` refers to subfunction `f`.

```
>> g(1).calls.fcnCalls
ans = 
  struct with fields:    
    names: {'input'  'find'  'norm'  'disp'  'log2'  'log2'  'pi'}
    lines: [1 2 3 4 6 6 6]

>> g(1).calls.innerCalls
ans = 
  struct with fields:    
    names: {'f'}
    lines: 3

>> g(2).calls.fcnCalls
ans = 
  struct with fields:    
    names: {'log2'  'log2'  'pi'}
    lines: [6 6 6]

>> g(2).calls.innerCalls
ans = 
  struct with fields:    
    names: {1×0 cell}
    lines: [1×0 double]
```

Other fields of `g` give **further details**, such as name

```
>> g(1).name
ans =
filename

>> g(2).name
ans =
f
```

or type

```
>> g(1).type
ans = 
  Script with no properties.

>> g(2).type
ans =
subfunction
```

### How to determine if a given function is used anywhere in the file

Obtain `g` as explained above, and then look for the desired function name in all `calls.fcnCalls.names` fields of `g`:

```
g = getcallinfo('filename.m');
sought_function = 'log2'; % or 'eig' in your case
t = arrayfun(@(x) x.calls.fcnCalls.names, g, 'UniformOutput', false);
    % collect all names of called functions. Gives a cell array of cell arrays
    % of strings (character vectors)
t = [t{:}]; % de-nest: concatenate into cell array of strings
result = any(strcmp(t, sought_function)); % compare with sought function name
```

Answer (score 1):

One option to check *by hand* would be to use the [profiler](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html).

I'm using a 2014 Matlab, i cannot run the previous example. However, as far as i saw on the [previous answer by Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46360465/2107764), it shows similar information but in a webpage style.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I would also suggest you use the profiler, which will list all called functions.

But to give you an alternative, if you are looking for just a single function (please see the disclaimer), you can utilize that functions in the current folder have precedence. Thus, say that you want to check if you use a function called `jacobianest`, then you create a new function in your folder called `jacobianest.m` with e.g.

```
function jacobianest(args)
error('jacobianest is being used')
end
```

then if the program terminates with that error, you are using `jacobianest`.

Disclaimer 1: This works only for the non-build-in functions. In the sense that if you type `edit *name of function*` and only comments come up, you cannot use this strategy. If the code itself shows up, you can.